# How to join tables including all ids from left table but only showing information from the right table given certain where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an attendees table with the following structure:

```
+--------------+---------+
| attendee_id  | others1 |
+--------------+---------+
|    abcd      | A       |
|    ghij      | B       |
|    defg      | C       |
+--------------+---------+
```

And also an eventattendees table with the following structure:

```
+--------------+---------+----------+
| attendee_id  | others2 | event_id |
+--------------+---------+----------+
|    wxyz      | D       |     1    |
|    mlno      | E       |     2    |
|    defg      | F       |     3    |
|    defg      | G       |     2    |
|    abcd      | H       |     1    |
+--------------+---------+----------+
```

What I want is to create a query that, given some event_id, returns a join of these tables (by attendee_id) that includes **all** attendee ids from attendee table and also returns the information from the eventattendde tables which a match for that **event_id**. Say, for event_id 3:

```
+--------------+---------+---------+----------+
| attendee_id  | others1 | others2 | event_id |
+--------------+---------+--------------------+
|    abcd      | A       |  null   |   null   |
|    ghij      | B       |  null   |   null   |
|    defg      | C       |    F    |     3    |
+--------------+---------+--------------------+
```

How can I do that for mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your `where` criteria in the `join` instead to respect the `outer join`.

```
select a.attendee_id, a.others1, e.others2, e.event_id
from attendees a
   left join eventattendees e on a.attendee_id = e.attendee_id and e.event_id = 3
```

If you put it in the `where` criteria, it will negate the `outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join

```
select a.attendee_id, a.others1, b.others2, b.event_id 
from attendees  as a 
left join eventattendees on a.attendee_id = b.attendee_id and b.event_id= 3;
```

Comment: Left join is the way to go, but the additional criteria should be defined in the JOIN.

Comment: I know .. seems obvious .. anyway i have updated the answer

Comment: As obvious as it can be, the accepted answer is the one with the criteria in the Left join.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT A.attendee_id, A.others1, ISNULL(B.others2,'empty') AS others2, ISNULL(B.event_id,'empty') AS event_id FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.attendee_id=B.attendee_id
```